# android UI Test with Espresso java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:

Tags: android, android-espresso, uitest

I do UITest with Espresso, and test login function in LoginActivity.java . 
when running LoginScreenTest.java ,some exception got,the follow is exception message. I don't konw why LoginPresenter can be found but LoadIdlingResource cannot be found ,why and how to do.thanks very much!!!
the following is exception message.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: bz/sunlight/soubei/util/LoadIdlingResource
atbz.sunlight.soubei.login.view.activity.LoginActivity.getCountingIdlingResource(LoginActivity.java:149)
at bz.sunlight.soubei.login.LoginScreenTest.setUp(LoginScreenTest.java:46)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
at android.support.test.internal.statement.UiThreadStatement.evaluate(UiThreadStatement.java:55)
at android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule$ActivityStatement.evaluate(ActivityTestRule.java:270)
at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
at android.support.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:59)
at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:262)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1739)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Class ref in pre-verified class resolved to unexpected implementation
at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClass(Native Method)
at dalvik.system.DexFile.loadClassBinaryName(DexFile.java:211)
at dalvik.system.DexPathList.findClass(DexPathList.java:313)
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:51)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
... 34 more
```

there are code :

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
@LargeTest
public class LoginScreenTest {
    public LoginPresenter loginPresenter;
    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<LoginActivity> mActivityRule = new ActivityTestRule(LoginActiv`enter herecode `ity.class);

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        loginPresenter = new LoginPresenter(mActivityRule.getActivity(), mActivityRule.getActivity());
        Espresso.registerIdlingResources(mActivityRule.getActivity().getCountingIdlingResource());

    }
}


public class LoginActivity extends BaseActivity {
    private LoginPresenter loginPresenter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        initView();
        loginPresenter = new LoginPresenter(this, this);
        loginPresenter.showLastUserName();
    }
    @VisibleForTesting
    public IdlingResource getCountingIdlingResource() {

        LoadIdlingResource loadIdlingResource = new LoadIdlingResource(this);
        return loadIdlingResource;
    }
}
```

Comment: try to rebuild the project. I've seen many times this error for nothing

Comment: can you paste line number 149 of login activity

Comment: Where is LoadIdlingResource defined? have you included it as a dependency with androidTestCompile?

Comment: I try to rebuild the project again,but it doesn't work.@OlegKhalidov

Comment: line 149 of loginActivity is  @VisibleForTesting
    public IdlingResource getCountingIdlingResource() {....},they already be showing in the code LoginActivity.java@Isaac

Comment: LoadIdingResource is in src/main/,then i do nothing ,How i include it as a dependency with androidTestCompile?@riggaroo

Comment: LoadldingResource is a .java file i build,not a  Library.@riggaroo